# How to add comma to summary result after using "Summarise function" from tidyverse

Tags: r

I did a sum of a column using the code below.

I have the correct number but it is not formatted properly as a number. I also have a case where I need it formatted as currency. This is the code I've tried

```
Result %>% 
  summarise(Pieces_Mailed = sum(Households, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  comma_format(digits = 12)
```

first case: it gave me 520698. How do i get it to return 520,698 instead?
second case: it gave me 46553549. How do i get it to return $4,655,354 instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`comma_format` just returns `,`

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tibble)
tibble(col = sample(1e5, 10, replace = FALSE)) %>%
       summarise(col = sum(col)) %>% 
       mutate(col = comma_format(accuracy = 12)(col))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  col    
#  <chr>  
#1 481,296
```

For adding `$`, we need `dollar_format`

```
tibble(col = sample(1e5, 10, replace = FALSE)) %>%
       summarise(col = sum(col)) %>% 
       mutate(col = dollar_format(accuracy = 12)(col))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  col     
#  <chr>   
#1 $445,896
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ akrun for always being the first responder to solving my problems. It worked perfectly.